# Chrome returns ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION error on file download

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I've implemented a mechanism to export and some information in a PDF in this way:

```
public void generatePdf() {
    String fileName = "Bolla_" + productionOrder.getOrderNumber();
    writePDFToResponse(new GenerateStatusPDF(companyInfo).generate(productionOrder), fileName);
}

private void writePDFToResponse(ByteArrayOutputStream baos, String fileName) {
    try {
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
        externalContext.responseReset();
        externalContext.setResponseContentType("application/pdf");
        externalContext.setResponseHeader("Expires", "0");
        externalContext.setResponseHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        externalContext.setResponseHeader("Pragma", "public");
        externalContext.setResponseHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment, filename=" + fileName + ".pdf");
        externalContext.setResponseContentLength(baos.size());
        java.io.OutputStream out = externalContext.getResponseOutputStream();
        baos.writeTo(out);
        externalContext.responseFlushBuffer();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my `.xhtml` file usage:

```
<h:commandLink>
                        <p:graphicImage name="/ultima-layout/images/pdf_icon.png"
                            width="64px" />
                        <p:fileDownload
                            value="#{productionOrderStatusView.generatePdf()}" />
                    </h:commandLink>
```

I don't why, but I'm facing some problem in the last days with this error:

```
ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_MULTIPLE_CONTENT_DISPOSITION
```

Where am I wrong? May be some new update in Google Chrome?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Filename may have comma.

Add a double quotes to your file name in general to avoid repeating characters, something like ("Content-Disposition", "attachment;filename=\"" + filename + "\"")

Please have a look at the standard. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition

Comment: Thank you! It has fixed the problem!

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my problem!